# Additional information: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblRubriek'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I have a schoolproject and I need to add data to 3 tables that are related to each other. My problem is that the primary key is related with the other and I recieve an error.

This is my code i'm running

```
    Protected Sub bntVerzenden_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bntVerzenden.Click


    Dim intGebruikersID, intRubriekID As Integer
    Dim VerkopenConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim VerkopenCommArtikel, VerkopenCommGebruiker, GebruikersIDComm, RubriekIDComm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand


    VerkopenConn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.SvShopConnection
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Connection = VerkopenConn
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Connection = VerkopenConn
    GebruikersIDComm.Connection = VerkopenConn
    RubriekIDComm.Connection = VerkopenConn


    'Gebruiker gegevens aan de database toevoegen
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblGebruiker (GebruikersNaam, GebruikersVoornaam, GebruikersEmail, GebruikersGSM) VALUES (@GebruikersNaam, @GebruikersVoornaam, @GebruikersEmail, @GebruikersGSM)"

    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersNaam", txtNaam.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersVoornaam", txtVNaam.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersEmail", txtEmail.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersGSM", txtGsm.Text)


    'GebruikersID uit de database halen
    GebruikersIDComm.CommandText = "SELECT tblGebruiker.GebruikersID FROM tblGebruiker WHERE tblGebruiker.GebruikersNaam = @Naam AND tblGebruiker.GebruikersVoornaam = @VNaam;"

    GebruikersIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", txtNaam.Text)
    GebruikersIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VNaam", txtVNaam.Text)

    'RubriekID uit de database halen
    RubriekIDComm.CommandText = "SELECT tblRubriek.RubriekID FROM tblRubriek WHERE tblRubriek.RubriekNaam = @RubriekNaam"

    RubriekIDComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekNaam", lstRubriek.SelectedItem.ToString)


    'Artikel gegevens aan de database toevoegen
    VerkopenCommArtikel.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblArtikel (ArtikelBeschrijving, ArtikelPrijs, RubriekID, ArtikelAankoopdatum, ArtikelTekoopgezet, ArtikelBeschikbaar, GebruikersID) VALUES ( @ArtikelBeschrijving, @ArtikelPrijs, @RubriekID, @ArtikelAankoopdatum, @ArtikelTekoopgezet, @ArtikelBeschikbaar, @GebruikersID)"

    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschrijving", txtArtikelBeschrijving.Text)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelPrijs", txtArtikelPrijs.Text)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekID", intRubriekID)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelAankoopdatum", CalAankoop.SelectedDate)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelTekoopgezet", calVerkoop.SelectedDate)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschikbaar", True)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersID", intGebruikersID)

    If VerkopenConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then VerkopenConn.Open()
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.ExecuteNonQuery()
    intGebruikersID = Integer.Parse(GebruikersIDComm.ExecuteScalar)



    intRubriekID = Integer.Parse(RubriekIDComm.ExecuteScalar)



    VerkopenCommArtikel.ExecuteNonQuery()






End Sub
```

At `VerkopenCommArtikel.ExecuteNonQuery()` Do I recieve this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblRubriek'.

[This is my Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ5bp.png)

Comment: If the PK is being generated in the parent table by the database then you need to retrieve that to put it in the child table before saving that.  See my guide to that here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052-Retrieve-Access-AutoNumber-Value-After-Insert&highlight=

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you! I think i've already managed to solve that problem, but now I ran into this one.

Comment: Before trying to convert to `Integer` you may need to first check if `ExecuteScalar` has returned `DBNull`, which could happen if the query returned no rows.

Comment: @GordThompson Would these work: `If Not DBNull.value.Equals(GebruikersIDComm.ExecuteScalar) Then
 intRubriekID = Integer.Parse(RubriekIDComm.ExecuteScalar)` or how to do I use `DBNull` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just tested it and if no rows are found then `ExecuteScalar()` returns `Nothing`. You can use the `IsNothing()` function to check for that. Also, my test suggests that you aren't using `Option Strict`, so implicit conversions can lead to strange behaviour. Put `Option Strict On` at the very top of your Module/Class file (and correct your code as required) to save yourself some grief.

Comment: Final comment (for now): It would be very helpful to see exactly what the OleDbException was. The error message *"An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"* is really just saying that "OleDb had some sort of problem". If you use `Try` / `Catch` you can display or log the actual `.Message` for the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
intRubriekID = Integer.Parse(RubriekIDComm.ExecuteScalar)
```

to retrieve the `intRubriekID` value *after* you have already set the Parameter value

```
VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekID", intRubriekID)
```

You need to execute the SELECT query first, then set the Parameter value for the `INSERT INTO tblArtikel` query, and then execute it.

Comment: I've changed the order so and now i get: Value can't be Null at 
`intGebruikersID = Integer.Parse(GebruikersIDComm.ExecuteScalar)`

Comment: My order of the executes where wrong, I managed to fix the order and the code works fine now, Thank you for helping!

Comment: You're welcome. Please do remember what I said about enabling `Option Strict`. I recommend that you tweak your Visual Studio configuration to make that the default for all new VB.NET projects. It's really a good idea.

Comment: I just enabled it on default!